# How to create .exe file for .net project and how to use it?

Tags: .net, ado.net

I have a .net  project (windows forms) of framework 4.0 @ visual studio 2010. how can i create an .exe file to invoke this project in a PC(of my friend) where i dont have .net visual studio. i want to use this exe file in that pc to use the windows forms there. Looking forward towards your reply.

In short,

1. how to create .exe file
2. how to use .exe file in my friend's computer of having no visual studio,.net framework and other stuffs

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

If you build the project in release mode and then look in the projects bin folder you will see a release folder. Your exe will be in here after building. Your exe file should run on your friends computer if they are running windows and have the .NET Framework installed.

Answer (score 1):

simple answer is: right click on the project in solution explorer (top right hand side window) and click 'build', then look for the exe file in ./bin/debug

You may also want to read on Visual Studio basics: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8w79z10.aspx

Comment: If you use the debug version it will be slower and larger as the compiler will not remove your debug functionality.